# Looping over and comparing/mutating class instances in a for loop results in unexpected behavior

Tags: python, for-loop, graph-theory

I have a class Node which represents a node on a directional graph. A Node contains a sequence (a string of letters, the 4 bases of DNA in this case), and a prefix and a suffix defined by the value k where the prefix is the first k letters and the suffix is the last k letters of the sequence.

If one Node's suffix is the same as another's prefix, the first Node should point to the second Node, and a Node can point to multiple other Nodes, but not to itself.

I'm reading in sequences from a file, making a list of Nodes out of them, and trying to set up the list "nextNodes", a property on each Node which contains all the Nodes that are pointed to by it.

Looping through the list of Nodes with two nested for-in loops, comparing every Node with every Node, results in the "nextNodes" list for each Node containing Nodes that should not be pointed to. Additionally, the list is the same for every Node.

I tried using the itertools.combinations method to compare Nodes, thinking the problem was somehow related to the for-in loops and multiple comparisons, but the same behavior occurs either way. I'm pretty sure the problem happens in the execution of the for loops but I have no idea what it is...??

Here's my code (Python 2.7):

```
import itertools

class Node():

    def __init__(self, name, seq='', k=3, nextNodes=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.seq = seq
        self.k = k
        self.nextNodes = nextNodes
        if len(seq) > k:
            self.prefix = seq[:k]
            self.suffix = seq[-k:]
        else:
            self.prefix = 'PREFIX'
            self.suffix = 'SUFFIX'

    # ...

    def getSeq(self):
        return self.seq

    def setSeq(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
        if len(seq) > self.k:
            self.prefix = seq[:self.k]
            self.suffix = seq[-self.k:]

    def getNextNodes(self):
        return self.nextNodes

    def setNextNode(self, node):
        self.nextNodes.append(node)

    def getPrefix(self):
        return self.prefix

    def getSuffix(self):
        return self.suffix

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

nodes = []
curNode = None
with open('seqs.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line[0] == '>':
            nodes.append(Node(line[1:].strip('\n')))
            curNode = nodes[-1]
        else:
            curNode.setSeq(curNode.getSeq() + line.strip('\n'))

# When either this for loop or the commented one runs, nextNodes is the
# same for every Node, and contains Nodes that should not be pointed to
for node in nodes:
    for otherNode in nodes:
        if node.getSeq() != otherNode.getSeq() \
        and node.getSuffix() == otherNode.getPrefix():
            node.setNextNode(otherNode)

"""
for node1, node2 in itertools.combinations(nodes, 2):
    if node1.getSeq() != node2.getSeq():
        if node1.getSuffix() == node2.getPrefix():
            node1.setNextNode(node2)
        if node2.getSuffix() == node1.getPrefix():
            node2.setNextNode(node1)
"""

for node in nodes:
    for nextNode in node.getNextNodes():
        print node, '->', nextNode
```

Example:
If 'seqs.txt' is:

```
>Node 1
AAACCCGGG
>Node 2
GGGTTTCCC
>Node 3
CCCGGGAAA
```

We would expect Node 1 to point to Node 2, which points to Node 3, which points to Node 1. But this is the output:

```
Node 1 -> Node 2
Node 1 -> Node 1
Node 1 -> Node 3
Node 2 -> Node 2
Node 2 -> Node 1
Node 2 -> Node 3
Node 3 -> Node 2
Node 3 -> Node 1
Node 3 -> Node 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here, I think, is using the list as a default value for nextNodes in your constructor for Node.  A list is mutable, so when you assign the default to self.nextNodes you're actually assigning the very same list, not a new list, to every node.  Then when you append to it in any Node, they all get that because they're pointing at the exact same list.  In effect, your appending to self.nextNodes is actually changing the default value.